# Getting started querying sync data from Realm

Tags: xamarin.forms, realm, mongodb-atlas

I'm attempting to get a list of items from a MongoDB Atlas instance via Realm into my Xamarin Forms application. I'm pretty sure I've followed the instructions correctly, however I can't seem to see any values come in.

I'm using Realm and Realm.Fody version: `10.2.0`

I've uploaded my data with the following script

```sh
mongoimport --uri mongodb+srv://[user]:[pass]@cluster0.[wxyz].mongodb.net/[company] --collection products --type json --file products --jsonArray
```

> 1057 document(s) imported successfully. 0 document(s) failed to import.

When I go to MongoDB Atlas, I see this
[image]

In my App.xaml.cs constructor, I create a realm app and log in with anonymous credentials

```cs
public const string MasterDataPartitionKey = "master_data";
ctor()
{
    var app = Realms.Sync.App.Create("my-app-id");
    app.LogInAsync(Credentials.Anonymous()).ContinueWith(task => User = task.Result);
}
```

After this, in my first ViewModel constructor (it's Rx, but isn't doing anything fancy)

```cs
ctor()
{
    _listProductsCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create<Realm, IEnumerable<Product>>(ExecuteLoadProducts);

    _listProductsCommand.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe(x => { /* checking for errors here */ }).DisposeWith(TrashBin);
    Initialize
        .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
                // note MasterDataPartitionKey is the value I've set on every single record's `_partitionKey` property.
        .Select(_ => new SyncConfiguration(MasterDataPartitionKey, App.User))
        .SelectMany(Realm.GetInstanceAsync)
        .Do(_ => { }, ex => {  /* checking for errors here */ })
        .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
        .InvokeCommand(this, x => x._listProductsCommand)
        .DisposeWith(TrashBin);
}
```

And later, a simple query

```cs
private static IEnumerable<Product> ExecuteLoadProducts(Realm realm)
{
    var data = realm.All<ProductDto>();
    var productDtos = data.ToList();
    var products = productDtos.Select(x => x.Map());
    return products;
}
```

**Expected**:
productDtos (and products) should have a count of 1057

**Actual**:
productDtos (and products) have a count of 0

I've looked in my Realm logs and I can see the connections and sync logs

[image]
[image]

My anonymous authentication is turned on

[image]

and I've made it so that all of my Collections have read access (in fact developer mode is on)

Here's an example of one of the records
[image]

Here's a snipped of the dto I'm trying to pull down
[image]

I feel as though I must be missing something simple. Can anyone see anything obvious that could be sending me sideways?

Comment: Could you show the code where you add "these 1000 objects".
Can you also confirm that you followed closely all the steps from https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/dotnet/quick-start-with-sync/?
Can you also confirm that you can see "these 1000 objects" in MongoDB Atlas?

Comment: Your screen shot of the console didn't show it, but should we assume that right below where it shows *Query Results 1-20 of Many* it's actually showing the correct objects? There could be a lot of reasons the data is not returned. For example, `ProductDto` is used in one spot and `Product` is used in another - probably not related but we kind of need to know one way or the other. Also, your app can only access the data of the partitionKey you've attached to. Do all of the objects have the correct partitionKey/is the partitionKey correct in code? Update the question and we'll take a look.

Comment: Oh. The code in the question is pulling local data only - can you include your Sync code so we can see how your app connects to Realm? It should look something like this section of code [Sync Realm](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/dotnet/quick-start-with-sync/#open-a-realm)

Comment: @Jay I've updated my question

Comment: @AndreaCatalini I've updated the question to ensure I cover your questions.

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, errors, models and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Images are ok as long as relevant code/errors are also textual. Images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Also, take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I am not a xamarin guy so forgive this comment; why are you doing this `var productDtos = data.ToList();`? Also, that query looks a little weird to me - did you check out the Query section in the docs to ensure it matches their query examples?

Comment: @Jay I did post the relevant code as text, and only images where images were necessary. I didn't want to post my modal as text because I don't want it searchable. I used `.ToList()` because Realm doesn't allow me to do `.Select()`. It's lazily evaluated and needs to be materialized before I can Select off of it. Also, there are no errors, zero errors, everything responds as though it's hooked correctly, just no values in `productDtos` OR inside the realm db on disk.

Comment: Well. I am not sure what you're expecting that query to do and data will contain your realm objects. Did you try to print data.Count() to see if anything being returned before the data is further manipulated?

Comment: yessir, the count is zero (0)

Comment: I don't know anything about Realm, but is there a way to get more info in the log at server side? verbose logging / log all queries / add debug print statements - anything like that? Need to know whether server side is doing what you expect. And if not, whether the problem is the request (query) that servers sees, or some problem in formulating the response. SImilarly, have you stripped the situation down to the simplest possible case?  For instance, if I had a mysql db that wasn't giving me anything, I might go back to truly basic queries, such as "tell me your version number".

Comment: ... related, any possible permissions issue?  Can server log both failure/success re permissions?

Comment: At a first glance there doesn't seem to be anything that's immeaditely addressable as wrong. You could open a [github issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues) where you can upload your full project (if that's feasible) for us to look better into it.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve the server is not logging any errors (it was when I had errors).

Comment: Your best bet is to start a new project, with the absolute minimum needed to get some response, any response, from server. Not (yet) the response you want, but the simplest possible request to a MongoDB. If that works, then you start adding to it, until you get to a version that doesn't work. Then open an issue at the link Andrea provided, and upload that project. If it works in a very simple case, such as a request for DB's version number, then mention that. (The purpose of the version number test, is that might have simpler permission requirements.)